# Slider jquery with issue on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a simple slider that works fine, but in the first seconds, maybe page load, it gets messed up, quite strange.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garttnzg/)

## JQUERY

```
var currentIndex = 0;// store current pane index displayed
var ePanes = $('#slider li'), // store panes collection
    time   = 3000,
    bar = $('.progress_bar');

function showPane(index){// generic showPane
    // reset bar
    bar.stop(true, true).css("width", 0).animate({'width': "100%"}, time, run);
    // hide current pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    // set current index : check in panes collection length
    currentIndex = index;
    if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = ePanes.length-1;
    else if(currentIndex >= ePanes.length) currentIndex = 0;
    // display pane
    ePanes.eq(currentIndex).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}

// apply start pane
showPane(0);

function run(){
    bar.width(0);
    showPane(currentIndex+1);
    bar.animate({'width': "100%"}, time, run);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slider is trying to load all the CSS elements on the page at once before the first slide completes it's action. Try adding `display: none;` to your `ul#slider li` to hide all of the elements from the start and adjust the `jQuery` accordingly.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garttnzg/1/)

Comment: tnks, but that adds a delay to the slider, cant we just show the first slide while still loading the other slides?

Comment: @user1765661 yes, that's why I mentioned "adjust the `jQuery` accordingly". Just have it load the first `li` in the `ul#slider` from the start or use CSS pseudo-classes to target the first `li`. For instance, `ul#slider li:first-child { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put your function declaration outside document ready and invoke it inside document ready/window.onload